# Tau Prolog - how to convert a prolog list into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, prolog, tau-prolog

I want to use Tau Prolog together with JavaScript on a Node Server, following [this tutorial](http://tau-prolog.org/manual/compatibility-with-nodejs), which works well. I need to convert the answers in a JavaScript compatible format, especially lists to arrays, or objects and vice versa.

I changed the Prolog program and goal in a way that it returns a list

Program: `test(t, [64,65,100,120]).`

Goal: `test(t, X).`

which returns with

```
console.log(session.format_answer(answer));

X = [64,65,100,120]
```

too the console.
How can I get only the list and assign it to a js variable?

I tried

```
answer.lookup("X")
```

which gives me

```
Term {
ref: 1258,
id: '.',
args: [
Num { is_float: false, value: 64 },
Term { ref: 1257, id: '.', args: [Array], indicator: './2' }
],
indicator: './2'
}
```

Which is not very comfortable to access.
The `args` array seems to be the list. I managed to get single list elements with

```
console.log(answer.links.X.args[1].args[1].args);
```

to get the third list element.
What is the best way to use complex answers and lists in JavaScript?

Comment: This might be of value: Tau-prolog examples [like](http://tau-prolog.org/examples/likes). If that works and as I don't plan to write an elaborated answer, the OP is free to elaborate and post as an answer. For others, let the OP earn some extra points.

Comment: I will say that learning Prolog effectively is hard. Learning to interface Prolog with another language is harder. Learning to use Prolog, interface with another language and then interface as a web site is a black art.

Comment: Thanks @GuyCoder, I got the mentioned  `answer.lookup("X");`  from this example. The basic mechanics are understood but not how to process more complex answers e.g. with lists, correctly. The likes example returns just one item an I can use its value. No problem to process it, but in my example I get back a list `X = [64,65,100,120]`. How do I go on from here.  I managed to get the values from the list, as described above with `answer.links.X.args[1]`  etc. but I guess there is a better way.

Comment: First I have not installed Tau Prolog and don't plan on it at the moment as I have way to many items I am juggling. Second, without seeing your entire code we are having to guess at it. It would be easier if you posted your code here or on GitHub or something and provided a link.  continued.

Comment: Third, I use SWI-Prolog and try to exclusively pass such information as JSON. After working with [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) and seeing how JSON can be used exclusively for such ([ref](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.json)) and then learning how to convert SWI-Prolog dicts to JSON ([json_write_dict/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=json_write_dict/2)), life became much easier.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913321/1243762) help? If not you note in your questions which previous SO answers you looked at and why they don't help with your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks again, I read every Tau Prolog related answer and all of them do not fit because thy are related to answers with atoms like `X = banana` not lists like `X= [64,65,100,120]` which I want to convert to JS arrays. I have the formatted answer of my goal so this part is not the problem, just how to extract the list from the answer in a way that I can easily convert it.

Comment: Sounds like you are the one on the cutting edge and will have to write or update the manual. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, I replicate [this answer](https://github.com/tau-prolog/tau-prolog/issues/280) here.

You can write a function to transform Prolog lists to arrays:

```
function fromList(xs) {
    var arr = [];
    while(pl.type.is_term(xs) && xs.indicator === "./2") {
        arr.push(xs.args[0]);
        xs = xs.args[1];
    }
    if(pl.type.is_term(xs) && xs.indicator === "[]/0")
        return arr;
    return null;
}
```

Example:

```
var session = pl.create();
session.query("X = [1,2,3].");
session.answer(a => console.log(fromList(a.lookup("X")))); // [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

Note that elements in array are still [Tau Prolog objects](http://tau-prolog.org/manual/prototypes-and-prolog-objects).